# Coq: (a :: L1) = (b :: L2) ⇒ a = b ∧ L1 = L2?

Tags: coq

This statement seems obvious to me, unless I'm overlooking some counterexample, but  I couldn't find anything in the Coq lists library that does this. Is there a command that does something to this effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be usually derived using the `injection` tactic. A version of the lemma for rewriting can be found in math-comp:

```
eqseq_cons (T : eqType) (x1 x2 : T) (s1 s2 : seq T) :
   (x1 :: s1 == x2 :: s2) = (x1 == x2) && (s1 == s2).
```